# using javascript operator-- new to me

Tags: javascript, operators

I'm tinkering with some code found here: http://www.benknowscode.com/2012/11/selecting-ranges-jquery-ui-datepicker.html

It's all pretty clear except for one line-- in the code two vars are set to -1. Then they are used like this:

```
var cur = -1, prv = -1;
prv = +cur; // what does this do?
console.log(prv); // results -1
console.log(cur); // results -1
```

I'm familiar with the `+=` usage-- but I haven't seen this usage before and don't understand why what appears to be `(-1) + (-1) = -1`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [**unary plus operator**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6) and it converts its operand to a number.

In the code you posted, it'd have no net effect. If, however, it had been this:

```
var cur = "-1", prv = -1;
prv = +cur;
```

then "prv" would be set to the numeric value `-1` instead of the string that's referenced by "cur".

Comment: @Pointy-- thanks! To be clear, is this essentially a shorthand way to type cast? Like using `parseInt`?

Comment: @user101289 yes exactly - just a quick way of doing it. If the value can't be converted, of course, you get a `NaN`.